# Directive updates to parent scope one step delayed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I moved my simple paging from controller to a directive and got stuck with a strange problem. Every time I update parent scope from within the directive it only gets updated on the next change. So if ng-options are [10,20,30] and I ng-change it to 10 - nothing happens. Then I change it to 20 and it updates to previous value of 10, next change to whatever value gets the model updated to the one I picked before, and so on

I tried to use $scope.$apply but it does not help. I still get delayed updates. What am I missing? I realize that it is something to do with digest update and $scope.$apply but I cant figure out where to use it. Anything I try just does not work.

Relevant controller parts:

```
vm.pages = 0;
vm.articles = [];

vm.load = { page: { batch: 10, current: 1 }
          , sort: { _id: -1 }
          , filter: {}
          };

vm.getArticles = function() {
  articleS.list(vm.load, function (data){
    vm.pages = data.pages;
    vm.articles = data.articles;
  });
}
```

The directive:

```
.directive("paging", function() {

  var scope = { update: '&', current: '=', pages: '=', batch: '=' };

  function link(s, e, a) {
    s.options = [10,20,50,100];

    s.toPage = function(p) {

      switch(p) {
        case "last":
          if (s.current != s.pages) {
            s.current = s.pages;
            s.update();
          }
          break;
        case "next":
          if (s.current < s.pages) {
            s.current ++;
            s.update();
          }
          break;
        case "prev":
          if (s.current > 1) {
            s.current --;
            s.update();
          }
          break;
        default:
          s.current = 1;
          s.update();
      }

    }
  }

  return {
    replace: true,
    scope: scope,
    templateUrl: 'paging.tpl',
    link: link
  }
});
```

The directive template:

```
<section class='pages'>
    <select
            ng-model="batch"
            ng-change="toPage('first')"
            ng-options="value for value in options">
    </select>
    <div>
      <button ng-click="toPage('first')"> 1 </button>
      <button ng-click="toPage('prev')"> << </button>
      <div>{{current}}</div>
      <button ng-click="toPage('next')"> >> </button>
      <button ng-click="toPage('last')"> {{pages}} </button>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Directive call:

```
      <paging
        update="vm.getArticles()"
        current="vm.load.page.current"
        batch="vm.load.page.batch"
        pages="vm.pages">
      </paging>
```

Comment: try using $scope.$apply() before  s.update(); sentence in directive

Comment: @ Anita That's the first thing I tried - no luck. Isn't the '=' in isolated directive scope supposed to take care of two way binding?

Comment: '=' creates isolate scope so it does only one way binding. You may try '&'  in place of '='.

Comment: @Anita In any case, I get `Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress` or `Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress`. I tried sticking the $apply everywhere - does not work.

Comment: in that case $apply won't work. try '&' in place of '=' in the directive.That might work

Comment: @r.sendecky Can you add demo fiddle or plnkr?

Answer (score 6):

OK. I figured this out.
If I understood correctly, $apply will generate a `already in progress` error if you run it on an isolated scope variable bound to its parent with '='. I think that '=' triggers the $digest (this is just an observation from trial and error while trying to solve this).

My problem was that `s.update()` function was run before the next digest cycle. So local scope variables "did not have time" to copy to the parent scope. That's why I could only see the update at the next operation or at the next digest cycle hens always seeing previous change.
Playing with `setTimeout(function(){ s.update() }, 2000)` proved it.
If I delay the execution for a couple of seconds then I see the update with correct changes. Delaying is not a solution though, slowing down application is plain stupid.
Then I found angular's `$timeout(function() {})`
This allows to skip the delay parameter which defaults to 0 and does not actually delay anything, but it does insure that callback runs on the next digest cycle so that the local scope variables can be updated to the parent.

```
if (s.current < s.pages) {
  s.current ++;
  $timeout(function() {
    s.update();
  });
}
```

Comment: That helped , Thank you :)